# Issue with setting picker view content

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uipickerview

In my app a user can change the number of picker view elements by clicking some buttons. Everything is ok with that. But after that I want to show a word in it but the picker view is probably not ready and the app just crashes. Here is the cod for that

```
- (IBAction)changeNumberOfLettersToShow:(id)sender {
    int numberOfLetters = (int)((UIBarButtonItem *)sender).tag;
    switch (numberOfLetters) {
    case 0:
        [self setNumberOfLetters:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 10] andLanguage:nil];
        break;
    default:
        [self setNumberOfLetters:[NSNumber numberWithInt: numberOfLetters] andLanguage:nil];
        break;
    }
    [self showTheFirstWordForNumberOfLetters:numberOfLetters];
}

- (void) showTheFirstWordForNumberOfLetters: (int) numberOfLetters{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfLetters], [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil] forKey:@"currentPositon"];
    NSArray *words = [allWordsForCurrentLanguage objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"language"], numberOfLetters]];
    [self displayWord:[[words objectAtIndex:0] uppercaseString] animated:YES];
}

- (void) setNumberOfLetters:(NSNumber *)numberOfLetters andLanguage: (NSString *) language {
    [pickerHelper setNumberOfLettersToShow:numberOfLetters andLanguage:nil];
    [self.picker reloadAllComponents];
}

- (void) displayWord:(NSString *)word animated:(BOOL)animated {
    pickerHelper.pickerWorkingAutomatically = YES;
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [word length]; i++) {
        NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [word characterAtIndex:i]];
        [self displayLetter:letter
            atComponent:i
               animated:animated];
    }
    pickerHelper.pickerWorkingAutomatically = NO;
}
```

The picker looks similar to the one on the picture:
http://sourcefreeze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/uipickerview-multi-selected-row.png

So I actually want to make a word from the fragments of a picker containing letters (which also user to work fine before I started doing it) and it actually works on a simulator.

UPDATED:

```
- (void) displayLetter:(NSString *)letter atComponent:(NSUInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUInteger row;
    if (animated){
        NSUInteger selectedRow = [self.picker selectedRowInComponent:component];
        row = selectedRow + ([self.alphabet count] - selectedRow % [self.alphabet count]) + [self.alphabet indexOfObject:letter];
    }
    else
        row = ((UINT16_MAX) / (2 * [self.alphabet count]) * [self.alphabet count]) + [self.alphabet indexOfObject:letter];

    [self.picker selectRow:row
               inComponent:component
                  animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly does the code crash? What is the error message from the crash?

Comment: [self displayLetter:letter atComponent:i animated:animated];
when i is more that 0 (at first I show a picker with only one column and that I want to see 3 columns in it)

'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {2147483680, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'

Comment: Update your question with the `displayLetter:atComponent:animated:` method.